# Php check if image is greyscale function memory leak

Tags: php, image-processing, memory-leaks

I'm using a function to check if an image is greyscale or not, the file paths and names are loaded in correctly and sometimes it runs fine.

However it's started to give the usual memory exhausted errors so I'm wondering what is causing this?

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in ... on line 51`

The line 51 is `$b[$i][$j] = $rgb & 0xFF;`

How can I optimize this function to use less memory, possibly only do half the image then work out an average or if the average is too high?

```
function checkGreyscale(){

    $imgInfo = getimagesize($this->fileLocation);

    $width = $imgInfo[0];
    $height = $imgInfo[1];

    $r = array();
    $g = array();
    $b = array();

    $c = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i<$width; $i++) {

        for ($j=0; $j<$height; $j++) {

            $rgb = imagecolorat($this->file, $i, $j);

            $r[$i][$j] = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g[$i][$j] = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b[$i][$j] = $rgb & 0xFF;

            if ($r[$i][$j] == $g[$i][$j] && $r[$i][$j] == $b[$i][$j]) {
                $c++;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($c == ($width * $height))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you need whole table in memory?

Not tested quickie:

```
function checkGreyscale(){

    $imgInfo = getimagesize($this->fileLocation);

    $width = $imgInfo[0];
    $height = $imgInfo[1];

    $r = $g = $b = 0; // defaulting to 0 before loop

    $c = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i<$width; $i++) {

        for ($j=0; $j<$height; $j++) {

            $rgb = imagecolorat($this->file, $i, $j);

            // less memory usage, its quite all you need
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

            if( !($r == $g && $r == $b)) { // if not greyscale?
                return false; // stop proceeding ;)
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

this way instead of storing all image bytes in memory, prolly more than doubling memory usage, you are using only most actual set of bytes you're running calculations on. Should work as far as you donn't load an image exceeding php memory limit at all.

Comment: I would have thought it would be better to test if `$r`, `$g` and `$b` are not equal and then return immediately if not - no point checking the rest as soon as one pixel isn't grey - it has to be faster than always checking all of them.